C acoustic recording program script hang
I use odroidN2+ and audio interface to record the acoustic data 24/7. After recording several files, the program hang.
When I check the program with the valgrind to check the heap summary, it mentioned as below. I suspect the issue was due to portaudio library. Therefore, I compiled the portaudio library inside the odroidN2+ but the issue still exists.
During my debugging, the program stuck  at the end of the recordCallback function and the recordCallback function was not triggered anymore by portaudio library and the program hang.
==1309067== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1309067==     in use at exit: 42,461 bytes in 81 blocks
==1309067==   total heap usage: 14,115 allocs, 14,034 frees, 1,489,720 bytes allocated
==1309067==
==1309067== 11 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 72
==1309067==    at 0x4849D8C: malloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==1309067==    by 0x10A383: main (in /home/odroid/acoustic/Recorder/Recorder_N2plus_10min)
==1309067==

==1309067== 112 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 54 of 72
==1309067==    at 0x484C0A4: calloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==1309067==    by 0x6243C2F: ???
==1309067==    by 0x4B4BD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x4B4C2F7: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x4B4F2CF: snd_pcm_open (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48A6593: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48A8B83: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48AB60B: PaAlsa_Initialize (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x489F723: Pa_Initialize (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x10A4FB: main (in /home/odroid/acoustic/Recorder/Recorder_N2plus_10min)
==1309067==
==1309067== 1,360 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 63 of 72
==1309067==    at 0x484C0A4: calloc (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm64-linux.so)
==1309067==    by 0x62572AB: ???
==1309067==    by 0x4B4BD03: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x4B4C2F7: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x4B4F2CF: snd_pcm_open (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48A6593: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48A8B83: ??? (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x48AB60B: PaAlsa_Initialize (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x489F723: Pa_Initialize (in /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libportaudio.so.2.0.0)
==1309067==    by 0x10A4FB: main (in /home/odroid/acoustic/Recorder/Recorder_N2plus_10min)
==1309067==
==1309067== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1309067==    definitely lost: 1,483 bytes in 3 blocks
==1309067==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1309067==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1309067==    still reachable: 40,978 bytes in 78 blocks
==1309067==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1309067== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==1309067== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==1309067==
==1309067== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==1309067== ERROR SUMMARY: 160 errors from 23 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

May I know how can I solve this recording hang issue?
My recording is as follows:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <portaudio.h>
#include <sndfile.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <libconfig.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define FRAMES_PER_BUFFER (512)
#if 1
#define PA_SAMPLE_TYPE  paFloat32
typedef float SAMPLE;
#define SAMPLE_SILENCE  (0.0f)
#define PRINTF_S_FORMAT "%.8f"
#elif 1
#elif 0
#else
#endif
const char * CurrentDateTime();
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2);
char wavefilename[45];
char equip[15];
SNDFILE      *outfileCB;
SF_INFO sfinfo;
char * FileNameHead;
int filesize,NUM_CHANNELS,SAMPLE_RATE,duration;
typedef struct
{
    int          frameIndex; 
    int          maxFrameIndex;
    SAMPLE      *recordedSamples;
}
paTestData;
static int recordCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
    unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
    const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo* timeInfo,
    PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
    void *userData)
{   printf("Being RecordCallBack *************** \n");
    int finished;
    static int  totalRead = 0;
    (void)outputBuffer; 
    (void)timeInfo;
    (void)statusFlags;
    (void)userData;
    finished = paContinue;
    if (totalRead * NUM_CHANNELS * 2 > filesize)
    {
        sf_close(outfileCB);
        char * BUFF_Time;
        BUFF_Time = CurrentDateTime();
        char* s4=concat(FileNameHead,BUFF_Time);
        char* outfilename=concat(s4,".wav"); 
        free(s4);
        if (!(outfileCB = sf_open(outfilename, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo)))
        {
            puts(sf_strerror(NULL));
            return  1;
        };
        sleep(1);
        copyString(wavefilename,outfilename);
        free(outfilename);
        totalRead = 0;
    } 
    int framesWritten = sf_writef_float(outfileCB, (const SAMPLE*)inputBuffer, framesPerBuffer);
    totalRead+= framesPerBuffer;
    return finished;
}
const char * CurrentDateTime()
{
    time_t raw_time;
    raw_time=time(NULL);
    static char strbuffer[16];
    strftime(strbuffer,16,"%m%d%Y_%H%M%S",localtime(&raw_time));
    return strbuffer;
}
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *result = malloc(len1+len2+1);
    memcpy(result, s1, len1);
    memcpy(result+len1, s2, len2+1);
    return result;
}
int main(void);
int main(void)
{
    PaStreamParameters  inputParameters;
    PaStream*           stream;
    PaError             err = paNoError;
    paTestData          data;
    int                 i;
    int                 numSamples;
    int                 numBytes;
    int                 DeviceIdTarget;
    int             isfocusrite;
    printf("patest_record.c\n"); fflush(stdout);
    config_t cfg;
    const char *EquipmentCC;
    const char *site;
    const char *area;
    filesize=0;
    NUM_CHANNELS=0;
    config_init(&cfg);
    if(! config_read_file(&cfg, "acoustic.cfg"))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d - %s\n", config_error_file(&cfg),
        config_error_line(&cfg), config_error_text(&cfg));
        config_destroy(&cfg);
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    filesize=SAMPLE_RATE*NUM_CHANNELS*duration*2;
    copyString(equip,EquipmentCC);
    data.maxFrameIndex = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER;
    data.frameIndex = 0;
    numSamples = FRAMES_PER_BUFFER * NUM_CHANNELS;
    numBytes = numSamples * sizeof(SAMPLE);
    SAMPLE recordedSamplesArr[numBytes];
    // data.recordedSamples = recordedSamplesArr;
    data.recordedSamples = (SAMPLE *) malloc( numBytes ); 
    if( data.recordedSamples == NULL )
    {
        printf("Could not allocate record array.\n");
        goto done;
    }
    for( i=0; i<numSamples; i++ ) data.recordedSamples[i] = 0;
    memset(&sfinfo, 0, sizeof(sfinfo));
    sfinfo.samplerate = SAMPLE_RATE;
    sfinfo.channels = NUM_CHANNELS;
    sfinfo.frames = 0;
    sfinfo.format = (SF_FORMAT_WAV | SF_FORMAT_PCM_16);
    char* Equipment=malloc(strlen(EquipmentCC)+1);
    strcpy(Equipment,EquipmentCC);
    char * BUFF_Time;
    BUFF_Time = CurrentDateTime();
    char* s1 = concat(site, "_");
    char* s2 = concat(s1,area);
    free(s1);
    char* s21 = concat(s2, "_");
    free(s2);
    char* s3=concat(s21,Equipment);
    free(s21);
    FileNameHead=concat(s3,"_");
    free(s3);
    char* s4=concat(FileNameHead,BUFF_Time);
    char* outfilename=concat(s4,".wav"); 
    copyString(wavefilename,outfilename);
    free(s4);
    config_destroy(&cfg);
    if (!(outfileCB = sf_open(outfilename, SFM_WRITE, &sfinfo)))
    {
        puts(sf_strerror(NULL));
        return  1;
    };
    free(outfilename);
    err = Pa_Initialize();
    if (err != paNoError) goto done;
    int numDevices =Pa_GetDeviceCount();
    if (numDevices < 0)
    {
        err = numDevices;
        goto done;
    }
    DeviceIdTarget=1;
    const   PaDeviceInfo *deviceInfo;
    const PaHostApiInfo *apiInfo;
    for (i = 0; i<numDevices; i++)
    {
        deviceInfo = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(i);
        apiInfo = Pa_GetHostApiInfo(deviceInfo->hostApi);
        isfocusrite=checkStringMatch((char *)deviceInfo->name, "Scarlett");
        if(isfocusrite&(deviceInfo->maxInputChannels>1)) DeviceIdTarget=i;
        if(deviceInfo->maxInputChannels==1) DeviceIdTarget=i;
    }   
    inputParameters.device = DeviceIdTarget; 
    if (inputParameters.device == paNoDevice) {
        goto done;
    }
    inputParameters.channelCount = NUM_CHANNELS;
    inputParameters.sampleFormat = PA_SAMPLE_TYPE;
    inputParameters.suggestedLatency = Pa_GetDeviceInfo(inputParameters.device)->defaultLowInputLatency;
    inputParameters.hostApiSpecificStreamInfo = NULL;
    err = Pa_OpenStream(
        &stream,
        &inputParameters,
        NULL,                
        SAMPLE_RATE,
        FRAMES_PER_BUFFER,
        paClipOff,
        recordCallback,
        &data);
    if (err != paNoError) goto done;

    err = Pa_StartStream(stream);
    if (err != paNoError) goto done;
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();  
    err = Pa_CloseStream(stream);//
    if (err != paNoError) goto done;
    sf_close(outfileCB);
    free(FileNameHead);
    cleanup:
    free(data.recordedSamples);
    done:
    Pa_Terminate();
    if (err != paNoError)
    {
        err = 1;
    }
    return err;
    free(Equipment);
}


Admittedly off topic: there is no such thing as a C script.

@Jabberwocky, I believe you never use portaudio before for recording.

You have made two guesses of the problem: library and memory leak. Both eliminated by recompiling and valgrind. Now connect a debugger and track down what the real problem is.

Hello @stark, during my recompilation, there is no error.

The reason I guess the problem is in library because, inside the valgrind's heap memory summary, it mentioned the Pa_Initialize().

Even if the library does have a small memory leak (and there are various ways that it could be a false positive), that would not cause it to hang.  So I think you're searching for the bug in the wrong place.  As stark mentioned, try single-stepping the code with a debugger, and then you can see where it is actually stuck, and can examine the state of the program to find out why.

Thank you for suggestion. I also debug the code. The program stuck at the end of the recordCallback function and the recordCallback function was not triggered anymore and the program hang. Normally the recordCallback function was triggered by portaudio library when the stream was opened by portAudio's Pa_OpenStream. So I am not sure how to solve the program hang issue since the recordCallback function was not triggered by library of portaudio.

You have UB (undefined behavior).
site is uninitialized
And, site is const char * so passing to concat arg char * would be flagged with -Wall.
Even with: char *site = NULL;, concat would need to change:
char *
concat(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t len1 = (s1 != NULL) ? strlen(s1) : 0;
    size_t len2 = (s2 != NULL) ? strlen(s2) : 0;

    char *result = malloc(len1 + len2 + 1);

    if (s1 != NULL)
        memcpy(result, s1, len1);

    if (s2 != NULL)
        memcpy(result + len1, s2, len2);

    result[len1 + len2] = 0;

    return result;
}

Same issue with FileNameHead

thank you for suggestion. Even with the modification based on your suggestion, the hang issue still exists.
